# Twilio VOIP VoiceCallBack Status issue

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

When Callee has no internet and caller place call, ringing volume play on caller side and at server Status CallBack Request following status flow occur :

**1.Initiated 2. Ringing 3. no-answer**

So the question is why Ringing callback status occur while callee has not network connection.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the dial number and how the terminating carrier handles calls for that number. It is really difficult to say.

Comment: Thanks to reply, I am talking about VOIP call.

Comment: Similar issue, the path to the VoIP device you are sending to may have a device called a Back-to-Back-UA (B2BUA) in the path which terminates and re-establishes the SIP session. It could be sending a 180-Ringing back to Twilio. "Ringing: Twilio has received a signal from our Super Network partner advising the destination phone is ringing."